# 4 X 4 multiplier signed using VHDL

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

```
entity mult4X4 is
    Port ( x : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           y : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           p : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end mult4X4;

architecture Behavioral of mult4X4 is

component hadder is
    Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC;
           b : in STD_LOGIC;
           sum : out STD_LOGIC;
           cout : out STD_LOGIC);
          
end component hadder;

component fa is
    Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC;
           b : in STD_LOGIC;
           cin : in STD_LOGIC;
           cout : out STD_LOGIC;
           sum : out STD_LOGIC);
end component fa;


signal x0y1 : std_logic;
signal x1y0 : std_logic;
signal x2y0,x1y1,x0y2,x3y2,x2y3,x3y3 : std_logic;
signal x3y0, x2y1,x1y2,x0y3,x3y1,x2y2,x1y3 : std_logic;
signal c00,c01,c10,c02,c11,c20,c03,c21,c22,c32,c322,c04,c05,c42,c323,c06,c52,c324 : std_logic ;
signal s1,s02,s2,s03,s13,s3,s04,s14,s4,s15,s5,s6,s7,s05,s06,s16,s07,s17 : std_logic;

begin

x1y0 <= x(1) and y(0);
x0y1 <= x(0) and y(1);
 comp00: hadder  port map ( a => x1y0, b => x0y1, sum => s1, cout => c00 );

x2y0 <= x(2) and y(0);
x1y1 <= x(1) and y(1);
x0y2 <= x(0) and y(2);
 comp01: fa  port map ( a=> x2y0, b => x1y1, cin => c00, cout => c01, sum => s02);
 comp10: hadder  port map ( a => s02, b => x0y2, sum => s2, cout => c10 );

x3y0 <= x(3) and y(0);
x2y1 <= x(2) and y(1);
x1y2 <= x(1) and y(2);
x0y3 <= x(0) and y(3);
 comp02: fa  port map ( a=> x3y0, b => x2y1, cin => c01, cout => c02, sum => s03);
 comp11: fa  port map ( a=> s03, b => x1y2, cin => c10, cout => c11, sum => s13);
 comp20: hadder  port map ( a => s13, b => x0y3, sum => s3, cout => c20 );
 


x3y1 <= x(3) and y(1);
x2y2 <= x(2) and y(2);
x1y3 <= x(1) and y(3);
comp03: fa  port map ( a => x3y0 , b => x3y1,cin => c02, sum => s04, cout => c03 );
comp21: fa  port map ( a=> s04, b => x2y2, cin => c11, cout => c21, sum => s14);
comp22: fa  port map ( a=> s14, b => x1y3, cin => c20, cout => c22, sum => s4);

x3y2 <= x(3) and y(2);
x2y3 <= x(2) and y(3);
comp04: fa port map ( a=> x3y0, b=> x3y1, cin => c03, sum => s05, cout => c04);
comp41: fa port map ( a => s05, b => x3y2, cin => c21, cout => c32, sum=> s15);
comp42: fa port map ( a => s15, b => x2y3, cin => c22, cout => c322, sum=> s5);

x3y3 <= x(3) and y(3);
comp05: fa port map ( a => x3y0, b =>x3y1, cin => c04,cout => c05,sum =>s06);
comp51: fa port map ( a => s06, b =>x3y2, cin => c32,cout => c42,sum =>s16);
comp32: fa port map ( a=> s16, b=> x3y3, cin => c322, cout => c323,sum =>s6);

p(0) <= x(0) and y(0);
p(1) <= s1;
p(2) <= s2;
p(3) <= s3;
p(4) <= s4;
p(5) <= s5;
p(6) <= s6;

comp06: fa port map ( a=> x3y0, b=> x3y1, cin => c05, cout => c06, sum => s07);
comp61: fa port map ( a=> s07, b=> x3y2, cin => c42, cout => c52, sum => s17);
comp52: fa port map ( a => s17, b=> x3y3, cin => c323, cout=> c324, sum =>s7);

p(7) <= s7;



end Behavioral;
```

this is my VHDL code for a 4 X 4 multiplier, I used bit extension to create them. After multiplying the results obtained are weird. In the simulation ( Xilinx vivado) I tried changing the radix to signed decimal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [4 by 4 multiplier unsigned](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/524256/4-by-4-multiplier-unsigned)

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of your earlier question.  A code dump, no results, a complaint, no actual question, no attempt at debugging, not even a testbench. This is an abuse of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with my first code, mentioned above. There should be a Full adder with a carry-in set to 1 at the last stage of sum bit 3 and all the partial products at the last row including the extended sign bit should be subtracted from the previous stages. i am pasting my edited version of my code with this comment for your reference. Thanks for reading and your time.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity mult4X4 is
    Port ( x : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           y : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           p : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end mult4X4;

architecture Behavioral of mult4X4 is

component hadder is
    Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC;
           b : in STD_LOGIC;
           sum : out STD_LOGIC;
           cout : out STD_LOGIC);
          
end component hadder;

component fa is
    Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC;
           b : in STD_LOGIC;
           cin : in STD_LOGIC;
           cout : out STD_LOGIC;
           sum : out STD_LOGIC);
end component fa;


signal x0y1 : std_logic;
signal x1y0 : std_logic;
signal x2y0,x1y1,x0y2,x3y2,x2y3,x3y3 : std_logic;
signal x3y0, x2y1,x1y2,x0y3,x3y1,x2y2,x1y3 : std_logic;
signal c00,c01,c10,c02,c11,c20,c03,c21,c22,c32,c322,c04,c05,c42,c323,c06,c52,c324 : std_logic ;
signal s1,s02,s2,s03,s13,s3,s04,s14,s4,s15,s5,s6,s7,s05,s06,s16,s07,s17 : std_logic;

begin

x1y0 <= x(1) and y(0);
x0y1 <= x(0) and y(1);
 comp00: hadder  port map ( a => x1y0, b => x0y1, sum => s1, cout => c00 );

x2y0 <= x(2) and y(0);
x1y1 <= x(1) and y(1);
x0y2 <= x(0) and y(2);
 comp01: fa  port map ( a=> x2y0, b => x1y1, cin => c00, cout => c01, sum => s02);
 comp10: hadder  port map ( a => s02, b => x0y2, sum => s2, cout => c10 );

x3y0 <= x(3) and y(0);
x2y1 <= x(2) and y(1);
x1y2 <= x(1) and y(2);
x0y3 <= x(0) nand y(3);
 comp02: fa  port map ( a=> x3y0, b => x2y1, cin => c01, cout => c02, sum => s03);
 comp11: fa  port map ( a=> s03, b => x1y2, cin => c10, cout => c11, sum => s13);
 comp20: fa  port map ( a => s13, b => x0y3,cin => '1', cout => c20,sum => s3 );
 


x3y1 <= x(3) and y(1);
x2y2 <= x(2) and y(2);
x1y3 <= x(1) nand y(3);
comp03: fa  port map ( a => x3y0 , b => x3y1,cin => c02, sum => s04, cout => c03 );
comp21: fa  port map ( a=> s04, b => x2y2, cin => c11, cout => c21, sum => s14);
comp22: fa  port map ( a=> s14, b => x1y3, cin => c20, cout => c22, sum => s4);

x3y2 <= x(3) and y(2);
x2y3 <= x(2) nand y(3);
comp04: fa port map ( a=> x3y0, b=> x3y1, cin => c03, sum => s05, cout => c04);
comp41: fa port map ( a => s05, b => x3y2, cin => c21, cout => c32, sum=> s15);
comp42: fa port map ( a => s15, b => x2y3, cin => c22, cout => c322, sum=> s5);

x3y3 <= x(3) nand y(3);
comp05: fa port map ( a => x3y0, b =>x3y1, cin => c04,cout => c05,sum =>s06);
comp51: fa port map ( a => s06, b =>x3y2, cin => c32,cout => c42,sum =>s16);
comp32: fa port map ( a=> s16, b=> x3y3, cin => c322, cout => c323,sum =>s6);

p(0) <= x(0) and y(0);
p(1) <= s1;
p(2) <= s2;
p(3) <= s3;
p(4) <= s4;
p(5) <= s5;
p(6) <= s6;

comp06: fa port map ( a=> x3y0, b=> x3y1, cin => c05, cout => c06, sum => s07);
comp61: fa port map ( a=> s07, b=> x3y2, cin => c42, cout => c52, sum => s17);
comp52: fa port map ( a => s17, b=> x3y3, cin => c323, cout=> c324, sum =>s7);

p(7) <= s7;



end Behavioral;
```